# Android MIT App Inventor: Sharing a video from the camcorder to Youtube

Tags: android, video, youtube, app-inventor

I have built the following blocks, as seen in the attached Picture.jpg file.
After the camcorder finishes the video recording, the following error message appears:

> Error 2001: The File file://content://media/external/video/media/17906
>   could not be found on your device.

A screenshot of the error message is attached herein (Picture.jpg).

Is there any solution for this problem?
How can a recorded camcorder video be shared to Youtube via an App Inventor application?

[image]
[Picture.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmD3F.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my [File extension](https://puravidaapps.com/file.php) and its `GetFileName` block

[image]

to first convert the content uri into a filename before sharing it.